# onclick doesnot working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I used onclick function in search.When I click search button,that not turns to script.I get the error like this,

Unknown action
The action 'create' could not be found for GeneralController

Can you give what I do ?

Comment: Please add your code (see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It means your controller called General has no create action. As your search button directed to that very action.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your code.

If you are writing the onClick function as a separate method in javascript, rails usually requires a onClick="window.method()".

Example
Rails HTML

```
<a onClick="window.message()"></a>
```

Javascript

```
window.message = function() {
    alert('hello!');
};
```

or CoffeeScript

```
window.message = ->
    alert 'hello!'
    return
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and reply.

Comment: Please mark answer correct and up vote. Looking to build my reputation and why I answered your question

Comment: I made a wrong id to pass in script.Now I correct it.Once again thanks guys #Keith, # TheCha͢mp , # YakovL , # Maxence